# Circuitikz siunitx and mathmode error?

Tags: math-mode, siunitx, circuitikz

So here's what I have right now:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, automata, positioning, matrix, calc}
\usepackage[RPvoltages, american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{steinmetz}
\begin{document}    
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw(0,0) to [V = $250\phase{\ang{0}}$] ++(0, 3) ;
        \end{circuitikz}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Right now, I am trying to enter either of the following into the bracket:

`[V = $\SI[parse-numbers = false]{250\phase{\ang{0}}} {\volt}$]`

Error: `Package tikz Error: (, +, coordinate, pic, or node expected. \draw(0,0) to [$\SI[parse-numbers = false]{`

`[V = $250\phase{\ang{0}}$ <\volt>]`

Error: `Argument of \XC@definec@lor has an extra }. ... [V = $250\phase{\ang{0}}$ <\volt>] ++(0, 3)`

I would like the siunit `V` to appear as usual. How to fix it?

Edit: I am also trying to do the same for an inductor:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, automata, positioning, matrix, calc}
\usepackage[RPvoltages, american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{steinmetz}
\begin{document}    
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw(0,0) to [$\SI[parse-numbers = false]{250\phase{\ang{0}}} {\volt}$] ++(0, 3) to[L = $j10$ <\ohm>] ++(3, 0);
        \end{circuitikz}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However, I am also getting an error saying:

`Package siunitx Error: Invalid token '$' in numerical input. \draw(0,0) to[L = $j10$ <\ohm>] ++(3, 0)`

How to fix this as well? Note that what I am trying to draw is based off of this:

[image]

Comment: One general thing: you have something containing `[]` inside an argument that is delimited by `[]`. In such cases you generally need to group the contents of the argument with `{}` so the parser isn't confused. I.e. `[{\SI[...]{...}}]`

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it didn't work.

Comment: I didn't actually say it would, it was as mentioned a general comment. Did you get the same error though?

Comment: Yes, I did get the same error.

Comment: You have to completely mask the = signs, see the manual around page 133, "caveats:". I don't have my pc now, but try `to [V=\mbox{...},...] `.  Will have a look tomorrow.

Comment: @Rmano your `\mbox` suggestion worked!

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here.

The first one is a bug/limitation of `circuitikz`; when passing parameters down, they are [not guarded with additional braces](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/346), so you have to protect all the characters significant to the Ti*k*Z parser (like `,`,`=`, `]`) several times. Although using a set of 8 (!) braces should suffice, I find that using an `\mbox{}` is easier.

The second one is that the "expedite siunitx syntax" with `<unit>` (which I personally don't like because I prefer the more clear `\SI{}{}`) works only for the structure *number`<`unit`>`*, so you have to remove the math switch.

Finally, this works:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[RPvoltages, american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{steinmetz}
\sisetup{copy-complex-root, complex-root-position=before-number}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw(0,0) to [V=\mbox{$\SI[parse-numbers = false]{250\phase{\ang{0}}} {\volt}$}] 
    ++(0, 3) to[L = j10<\ohm>] ++(3, 0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]